# Swift: Change the tabBar icon from appDelegate

Tags: swift, notifications

I would like to change an icon of my tabbar from the appDelegate.

I will explain why I want to do that.

From my website I send data by push to my application, so in the appdelegate I recieve the data in the function didReceiveRemoteNotification, with these data I create a local notification manually. I would also like to be able to modify the icon of my TabBar to show that there is a new notification.

So how to change the icon of the tabbar from the app delegate?

Here is a photo of my app, the green circle is the part that means "New notification"

[My App images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWRNs.png)

Here my code in appdelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification data: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
    if let data = data as? NSDictionary {
        print("Title: \(data)")

        LocalNotification.createLocalNotificationWithIntervals(identifier: "Push",
            title: data["title"] as! String,
            body: data["body"] as! String,
            intervals: 1) { error in

            guard error == nil else {
                print("Error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            print("Successfully execute notification")
        }
    }
}
```

I user a tabor controller:

```
class FittoTabBarController: UITabBarController {

let kImageNoLabelInset: CGFloat = 6.0

var selectedTab: FittoTabBar.Tabs = .pods {
    didSet {
        selectedIndex = selectedTab.rawValue
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    selectedTab = .pods
    removeItemsTitles()
}

override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    guard let selectedItemIndex = tabBar.items?.index(of: item),
          let selectedTab = FittoTabBar.Tabs(rawValue: selectedItemIndex) else {
        return
    }

    self.selectedTab = selectedTab
}

private func removeItemsTitles() {
    if let items = self.tabBar.items {
        for item in items {
            item.title = ""
            item.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: kImageNoLabelInset, left: 0.0, bottom: -kImageNoLabelInset, right: 0.0)
        }
    }
}
```

The input of my application is on the tabbar controller

Comment: How you are setting the TabBar? Please post the code for the same.

Comment: Hey check the edit please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the code provided above, You need to follow these steps to make it working.

1. In your `FittoTabBarController` add these methods.

   ```
   func setBadge(_ value: String?) {
       _ = self.viewControllers![2].tabBarItem.badgeValue = value
   }

   func getBadge() -> String? {
      return self.viewControllers![2].tabBarItem.badgeValue
   }

   func resetBadge() {
      self.viewControllers![2].tabBarItem.badgeValue = nil
   }
   ```
2. In your appDelegate, get the rootViewController of your window, on receiving notification

   ```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification data: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
   if let data = data as? NSDictionary {
       print("Title: \(data)")

       let myTabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as! FittoTabBarController
       var newBadgeCount = "1"
       if let currentBadgeCount = myTabBarController.getBadge() {
           // Convert to int
           var intValOfCurrentBadge = Int(currentBadgeCount)!

           // Increaset it by one.
           intValOfCurrentBadge = intValOfCurrentBadge + 1

           // Convert back to string.
           newBadgeCount = "\(intValOfCurrentBadge)"
       }

       // Set your badge value here.
       myTabBarController.setBadge(newBadgeCount)

       // ADD YOUR EXISTING CODE HERE
   }
   }
   ```
3. when user clicks on the 3rd tab, just call the resetBadge() method to remove the badge count.

Hope it helps.